# Laravel - read route name, how if had group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, get, laravel-routing

My question is how I can read current route name in **Laravel FW** if I have for example this route group:

```
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'machines'], function(){
        // GET
        Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'ServerController@index', 'as' => 'machines'));
        Route::get('/update/{id}', array('uses' => 'ServerController@update', 'as' => 'machines.Update')); 
        //POST
        Route::post('/updatePost/{id}', array('uses' => 'ServerController@updatePost', 'as' => 'machines.UpdatePost'));

        });
```

Normally I'm reading this value with: `Route::currentRouteName()` but it working only to `Route::get('/', ***);` and does not work for (for example: `Route::get('/update/{id}');` which name is 'machines.Update'. It's returning nothing.

Why I'm doing this? Im trying to create "active menu". For now, my function presenting like this:

```
HTML::macro('nav_link', function ($route, $title, $parameters = array()) {

$class = '';

if(Route::currentRouteName() == $route) {
    $class = ' class="active" ';
} else {
    $class = '';
}

return '<li' . $class . '>' . link_to_route($route, $title, $parameters = array()) . '</li>';

});
```

and

```
{{ HTML::nav_link('dashboard', 'Dashboard', array()); }}
{{ HTML::nav_link('machines', 'Machines', array()); }}
```

I want to create "dynamic" macro which will create `<li>` items and it will check if it is the active item and next will give them active state by `class="active"`.

**SOLUTION:**

In Laravel 4.1 function `Route::currentRouteName()` was changed to `Route::current()->getName()` and now it working as hell :)

For posterity:

```
HTML::macro('nav_link', function ($route, $title, $parameters = array()) {

$class = '';

if(strpos(Route::current()->getName(), $route) !== false) {
    $class = ' class="active" ';
} else {
    $class = '';
}

return '<li' . $class . '>' . link_to_route($route, $title, $parameters = array()) . '</li>';

});
```

Usage:

```
{{ HTML::nav_link('machines', 'Machines', array()); }}
```

It's working code for "dynamic active menu".

Comment: Where are you using currentRouteName? Why?
EDIT: Also, seems that in Laravel 4.1 currentRouteName has been replaced. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2919

Comment: Yes but it's working for now (still). I'm trying to do the "active menu", by comparing the names of routes.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, use Request::is

```
<li {{ Request::is('portal') ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>
    <a href="{{ URL::route('admin.dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

Comment: You can also use wildcards, e.g. Request::is('update/*')

Comment: Its ok for "manual check" but look now on my question I edited it.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 4.1. A second before I found function in documentation that returns what I wanted (it was hard). `Route::currentRouteName()` in Laravel 4.1 was changed to `Route::current()->getName()` and now it properly returning what I wanted.